# How to create phpunit testcase for file upload functionality in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, testcase, mockery

**Controller.php**

```
public function uploadDocument($request,$profileId)
{
   $s3Bucket = 's3.' . $request->input('fileType');
   $file = $request->file('document');
   $name = $file->hashName();
}
```

**Testcase.php**

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mockery;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

public function testUploadDocumentSuccess()
{
   $test = new \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile(public_path('laravel-test-img.jpg'), 'laravel-test-img.jpg', 'image/jpg', 
            filesize(public_path() . '/laravel-test-img.jpg'), true);

   $request = new Request([
      'fileType' => 'profile',    
      'document' => $test
   ]);
    
   $response = $this->documentService->uploadDocument($request, 1);
   $this->assertIsArray($response);
}
```

For doing unit testing, using mock object to call the every class. Not calling endpoint directly by passing route name.

**Query**

Always getting null from `$request->file('docuemnt')` when accessing file data by request object passing from testcase function.

I have tried many ways and find out the solution on web but most of all gives solution by calling the route personally like

```
$response = $this->action(
   'POST',
   'FileStorageController@store',
   $values,
   ['file' => $uploadedFile]
);
```

Comment: As the other user stated, it is very important that you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#storage-fake) as it is exactly explaining how to achieve what you want...

Answer (score 1):

You can probably explore mocking the file via the `mock()` method. You can find out more here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#storage-fake.

Sample provided by Laravel:

```php
<?php
 
namespace Tests\Feature;
 
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Tests\TestCase;
 
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_albums_can_be_uploaded()
    {
        Storage::fake('photos');
 
        $response = $this->json('POST', '/photos', [
            UploadedFile::fake()->image('photo1.jpg'),
            UploadedFile::fake()->image('photo2.jpg')
        ]);
 
        // Assert one or more files were stored...
        Storage::disk('photos')->assertExists('photo1.jpg');
        Storage::disk('photos')->assertExists(['photo1.jpg', 'photo2.jpg']);
 
        // Assert one or more files were not stored...
        Storage::disk('photos')->assertMissing('missing.jpg');
        Storage::disk('photos')->assertMissing(['missing.jpg', 'non-existing.jpg']);
 
        // Assert that a given directory is empty...
        Storage::disk('photos')->assertDirectoryEmpty('/wallpapers');
    }
}
```

Comment: Will update you Aaron once i will try it.